# Unable to start activity with asmack.jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the following weird problem.

My main activity looks like this:

```
public class CityGame extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, XMPPClient.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

 }
}
```

I striped the code down to find the problem. The code above does nothing more then jumping directly to the XMPPClient activity. XMPPClient activity is using the asmack.jar library and that library is added to my eclipse build path.

The XMPPClient activity code:

```
public class XMPPClient extends Activity {

/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "onCreate called");

    //Create a connection to the jabber.org server.
    Connection conn1 = new XMPPConnection("jabber.org");
    try {
        conn1.connect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

The problem occurs when I call functions from the asmack.jar lib. For instance the `conn1.connect();` crashed my application over and over again. I get errors like:

```
06-07 09:05:03.085: E/AndroidRuntime(538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 09:05:03.085: E/AndroidRuntime(538): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joop.citygame/com.joop.citygame.XMPPClient}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-07 09:05:03.085: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
06-07 09:05:03.085: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
06-07 09:05:03.085: E/AndroidRuntime(538):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.joop.citygame"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".CityGame" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".XMPPClient" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.joop.citygame.XMPPClient" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

INFO: API level 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establishing a remote connection can take a long time. 
You are trying to establish a connection directly from an activity and by default this activity is bound to the UI thread.

As a result, as long as your activity is trying to establish the connection, the user interface is blocked. The user cannot press any button and the screen is frozen.

By throwing a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) the android operating system is forcing you to change your implementation and is forcing you to establish your connection from another thread.

To summarise, you should not try to establish your remote connection from the UI thread. Try to establish it from a [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).
If you really want to establish it from an activity try to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html).

**EDIT :** Take a look at the android [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) :

> StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network
>   access on the application's main thread, where UI operations are
>   received and animations take place.

It might be enabled for your application.

Comment: My code has also a diskwrite violation :P
Probably asmack is writing to the disk

Comment: That's possible. :) How did you chose to solve the problem finally ?

Comment: Added the strictmode code to my onCreate() and watched the LogCat.
Very useful.
But I still need to make an extra thread for the connection.
Is Android 4 forcing developers to implement it that way?

Comment: I don't think android 4 if forcing you to implement it that way. But probably asmack does.

Comment: When your done with your problem, you can select an answer as "the answer to your question". That way you make it easy to futur readers to understand witch is the correct solution. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: "The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it’s heavily discouraged. "

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about the SDK target. :)

Answer (score 0):

// you need to add in XMPPClient this activity in your manifest file

and add network permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

//need to mention like this not like `("jabber.org")`

```
Connection conn1 = new XMPPConnection("http://www.jabber.org");
```

Answer (score 0):

No IO is allowed in the main thread. You need to create an AsyncTask and run your connection code there.